# Espresso test with phone asleep

Tags: android-espresso, android-testing

I'm tryig to build a test farm, but I found one large hurdle with it. The Espresso tests can't run when the phone is asleep.

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?
```

Yeah, I know I can set it to never sleep in Developer options, but I don't want do kill the phone's displays. I also tried enabling Daydream, but it has the same issue.

Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `Activity`'s `onCreate` method like this:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }
    //
    // Your code ...
    //
}
```

You shouldn't need any permissions for that, and it happens only on `DEBUG` builds.